# Find resource path Image.FromFile

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image, path

I am trying to play a .gif image but I am having a problem with finding the correct path. I am assuming I shouldn't have to use C:\ on my computer, because it wouldn't work on another computer. I have to return a string, not sure why this is so hard.

Code:

```
Private GIFAnim As Image = Image.FromFile(Resources\book.gif)'<--- Error
Private frames As Integer
```

I have tried:

```
Private GIFAnim As Image = Image.FromFile(bin\book.gif)
```

and

```
Private Sub btnTurnFwrd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTurnFwrd.Click

   Private GIFAnim As Image = Image.FromFile(theGif)

    Dim theGif As String = Application.ExecutablePath
        theGif = theGif.Substring(0, _
            file_name.LastIndexOf("\bin")) & _
            "\book.gif"

    frames = GIFAnim.GetFrameCount(Imaging.FrameDimension.Time)
    ImageAnimator.Animate(GIFAnim, AddressOf paintFrame)

End Sub
```

and

```
Private GIFAnim As Image = Image.FromFile(My.Resources.book.gif)
```

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to hard

```
Private GIFAnim As Image = My.Resources.book.gif
```

work fine